# mySQL getting rank from score

Tags: php, mysql

i have numbers from my table fields score, i want to `fill/add` the rank field according to score like below. How i can do this?

```
Score  -->  Rank
75        
82       
83        
75        
90        
78        
78        
75        
80        
73        
76
```

this make like this when we sort it out:

```
Score  >  Rank
90        1
83        2
82        3
80        4
78        5.50
78        5.50
76        7
75        8.50
75        8.50
75        8.50
73        11
```

Rank is blank at first, then i update it, or create new field to fill in the rank

Comment: Is the rank already a column in the table? Then just use `ORDER BY rank`.

Comment: rank is blank first, or it could be another field created by query that creates the rank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused how you get 5.5 vs 5 and 8.5 vs 8 (or even 9), but if you're looking for the row number or the ranking, then you can use user-defined variables:

```
SELECT y.score, y.score/z.maxscore perc, 
  @rn:=@rn+1 rn,
  @rnk:=IF(@score=y.score,@rnk,@rn) rnk,
  @score:=y.score
FROM yourtable y
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(score) maxscore
        FROM yourtable) z
  JOIN (SELECT @score:=-1,@rnk:=0,@rn:=0) t
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95314/1)

If you're always looking for ranking + 0.5, easy enough to add that to the above query.  Just didn't understand the logic completely.

Comment: yes, i know i doesn't seems to have logic, i don't know why my client want to have this, anyway, i don't know mySQL can do this stuff though found some weird characters like @:= in the code, anyway thanks.

Comment: @user1999194 -- np, glad I could help.  mysql user-defined variables can be pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Min and Max values of Score, then

```
UPDATE table SET rank= ((Score-@Min)/(@Max-@Min))*9+1
```

This will rank from 1-10.  change the 9 accordingly to your rank limits.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the average rank takes a bit more work;

```
select t.score, (minrank + maxrank) / 2.0 as rank
from t join
     (select t.score, min(rank) as maxrank, max(rank) as minrank
      from (select t.score, @rn = @tn + 1 as rank
            from t cross join (select @rn := 0) const
            order by t.score desc
           ) t
      group by t.score
     ) tr
     on tr.score = t.score
```